# Compare 2 lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get all date values from dateRange where each datetime is the `DayOfWeek.Friday`,..`Monday`,..`Sunday`.

The Intersect did not work because I guess those 2 lists are not real intersections... and they have a different type: DateTime vs. Enum.DayOfWeek

This gives me only all fridays but I also want the Mondays,Sundays... without using the OR operator.

```
var dateRange = _dateService.GetDateRange(startDate, endDate).Where(d => visibleWeekDays.Any(v => d.DayOfWeek == v)).ToList();
```

These are both lists I have to compare somehow:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dateRange = _dateService.GetDateRange(startDate, endDate);
IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> visibleWeekDays = new List<DayOfWeek>
{
    DayOfWeek.Friday,
    DayOfWeek.Monday,
    DayOfWeek.Sunday,
};
```

Please DO not write the full ling query as solution.
Just write the linq extension methods in random order I have to use to solve the riddle.
Just for the funs and learning sake :)

**UPDATE**

See my input datetime values and the output I want:

[image]

BUT be aware, the visibleWeekDays list is not static. There can be a dynamic number of values in this collection. Therefore I can and do not want to use the && or || operator.

Comment: can you explain what you are attempting to accomplish? can you show what the expected i/o is?

Comment: its not appropriate to give the answer in a random order. this question could be a benefit to future readers. i have edited your question to remove that comment.

Comment: See my answer, it will provide the output that you have defined.

Comment: Dump the content of `dateRange` to see if it contains only Fridays. Your code should work. @Oliver's code is better I suppose.

Comment: Your query should work. Are you sure there is no problem with an `GetDateRange`?

Comment: I updated my question with an IMAGE input/output.

Comment: Sorry guys, my unit test setup was for FRIDAY ONLY argh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find yourself in a position of wanting an intersection, but where the types of the two collections aren't the same, it usually means you want a `Join`. An intersection, by definition, is a join in which the two collections are of the same type, where the key selector is "itself", and where the result selector just picks one of the items at random (since they must be equal, by the definition of intersection).  Since not all of these restrictions apply to you all you need to do is step out to the more general `Join`.

Just as a demonstration of this, here is an implementation of `Intersect` using just `Join`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first
    , IEnumerable<T> second, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return first.Join(second, x => x, x => x, (a, b) => a, comparer);
}
```

The `DayOfWeek` can just select itself as a key, and then you just need a method of getting a `DayOfWeek` object out of a `DateTime` for the key selector.  For your result selector you only need to grab the `DateTime` object; you shouldn't need the `DayOfWeek` object anymore.

Whenever you see yourself writing a LINQ solution that has a `Where(x => collection.Any(...` or `Contains` or some other search operation inside of a `Where` odds are you should be using a `Join` instead, if applicable (you should at least ask yourself if you should be using a `Join`).

Since you don't want a full implementation I'll put it below in a spoiler tag.  Don't look at it if you want to write the code yourself:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable FilterDaysOfWeek(IEnumerable dates
>     , IEnumerable daysOfWeek)
> {
>      return dates.Join(daysOfWeek
>          , date => date.DayOfWeek
>          , day => day
>          , (date, day) => date);
>  }
> ```

Comment: yeah then it was easy using query style: var query = from d in dateRange
                        join v in visibleWeekDays on d.DayOfWeek equals v
                        select new { VisibleDate = d };

Comment: @Elisa You don't need/want to create a new anonymous object just to hold onto the date.  Just `select d` and be done.  Other than that, yes, that will work just fine.  It's mostly personal preference as to whether not to use query vs method syntax.

Comment: ah right... I am used to the ext method style nearly never use the query style. But with the join the query style is easier. I prefer your solution over the contains()/Any() because it seems semantically more correct and obvious what is going on :)

Comment: @Elisa Yeah, in this particular case I choose to use method syntax because it highlighted the difference between a `Join` and an `Intersect`.  You'll notice, between the two `Join` calls in my answer the only difference is in the first key selector (and in the variable names and whitespace, but they don't really count).  The symmetry in that comparison was just too good to pass on.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert DayOfWeek to an integer, you can do a simple > and < comparison to get valid values, so just a .Where query should be good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the dates in `GetDateRange` that have a `DayOfWeek` that matches those in `visibleWeekdays` you could use the following Linq statement:

```
 _dateService.GetDateRange(startDate, endDate)
             .Where(d=> visibleWeekdays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek));
```

Below is a full test of this in action:

```
class Test
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var weekdays = new[] { DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday };
            var result = GetDateRange(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(14))
                .Where(d => weekdays.Contains(d.DayOfWeek));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            DateTime date = start;

            do
            {
                yield return date;
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            }
            while (date < end);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you read my non working sample with the .Any() its the same behavior as the Contains(). It returns only Friday`s...

Comment: I see, what's GetDateRange doing?  Is it definitely outputting the correct dates?

Comment: It gets a datetime values from startDate to endDate. There is no filtering.

Comment: Ahh! That explains it, I have just added a test example.

Comment: Yes and my former .Any() works too. But I must admit that I prefer the solution from Servey.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Contains` on the `visibleWeekDays` in your `Where` clause.

Comment: That might make the code look a tad bit cleaner, but it wouldn't perform any differently.

Comment: @Servy: The `Any` version is hard to read, `Contains` is not. The OP did not ask for a different functional version, merely a working one. `Join` has different semantics, but given the size of the inner list the optimized version is probably using a simple list for the inner, making the difference minimal.